# R, sapply( XXX, get) not working within a function

Tags: r, function, get, sapply

`R` question.

Why the following code gives me an error of `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found`?

code:

```
foo = function(a = 1, b = 2){
  return(sapply(ls(),get))
}
foo()
```

I am expecting the function would return

```
a b 
1 2
```

-- PS, following codes work.

```
foo = function(a = 1, b = 2){
  return(get("a"))
}
foo() #1

foo = function(a = 1, b = 2){
  return(ls())
}
foo() # "a" "b"

foo = function(a = 1, b = 2){
  return(sapply(ls(),function(x) x))
}
foo() # "a" "b"
```

Comment: `return(sapply(ls(),get, envir = environment()))` otherwise `get` searches into `sapply`'s environment

Comment: Never knew how to specify an environment...